# Selecting Attributes along with MAX value

Tags: mysql, join

I have the MySql Tables connected by foreign keys as follows

```
Person(Driver_id, Name, Address)

Car(Reg_no, Model, Year)

Owns(Driver_id, Reg_no)

Accident(Report_no, Date, Location)

Participated(Report_no, Driver_no, Reg_no, Damage_amt)

Car Values:
KA35F2845 | Fiat Punto   | 2013 |
KA25Y1878 | Audi A4      | 2015 |

Participated Values:
1 | 101| KA35F2845  |      10000 |
2 | 102| KA25Y1878  |      30000 |
```

> Requirement: I want to display Model of the Car having highest Damage_amt using Join.

Below is the code I tried:

```
select c.model from car c join (select reg_no,max(damage_amt) from participated) p on c.reg_no=p.reg_no;
```

This query is selecting the Maximum value and the First value in the Car Table, not the corresponding value of Maximum value.

> Expected Output: Audi A4
>
> Output got:Fiat Punto

Comment: Database structure problem, query is working fine, what is your p.reg_no?

Comment: That is the 'reg_no' obtained from the query(written after join), for equating with car reg_no. Can u pls tell me what is the Structure problem..

Comment: what is the value of it & c.reg_no? as I created the same table you suggest and it gives me "Audi A4" output as well. I've placed value like 'KA35F2845' in Participated table Reg_no column

Comment: In this sample input, it is 'KA25Y1878'. But everytime it is not fixed. The reg_no of max amount has to be selected dynamically.

Comment: In your question car table Reg_no field is on first number so value will KA35F2845 and KA25Y1878, and Participated table field Reg_no value is 101 and 102 , so KA35F2845  and 101 never gonna match, you have to change field...

Comment: Ya, that was my typing mistake. I have edited that in the question. Kindly check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested one query as per given your data and result is `Audi A4`, Please this query

```
SELECT car.model FROM car join participated on car.reg_no=participated.reg_no WHERE  damage_amt=(SELECT max(damage_amt) FROM participated);
```

Comment: Its working fine. Got the correct output. Thanks a lot.